Sharepoint List Board View not showing all cards
I have a large Sharepoint List on Sharepoint Online that has about 500 projects in it. When using classic list view, it shows every item and all filters work properly.
When we view the list in Board view it does not show all the cards. We are filtering on Project Size. Large and Medium are all showing properly but Small does not. The board column shows the number that should be there but does not show all the cards. ie the column shows 7 but there are only 2 cards.
If I open the filter in the sidebar and deselect Small, then reselect Small, it shows all the cards. If I try to save the view with those filters, it reverts to showing only some of the cards.
Are the List Settings > Views > Filters conflicting with the views in the Filters in the sidebar (Funnel icon)?
